# Rails : Is it possible to put a "create" form on a "index" or "show" view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to work on my first rails project and was wondering if it was possible to combine the show or index view (of photo albums) with a form that creates more photo albums. Would the URL not have the correct parameters to do this? Would I be able to set the action on the form to make it "create" and redirect_to the index page again on success?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do this, just put the form code on whatever page you want to create/update from and it will work.

The only issue is where the action would redirect you to after a successful or unsuccessful create/update: usually from the `new` page, you would redirect to the newly-created record (`show` action for the new record) on success and back to the `new` action on failure (with the errors on the form fields). If you want to create/update records from different pages, and have the action redirect to different pages in each case, then you'll have to do just a bit more work.

On possibility would be to add a hidden parameter to the form with the action to redirect to, and make the action check for it and redirect accordingly. For example:

```
VALID_REDIRECT_ACTIONS = ["show", "index"]

def create
  ...
  if @photo.save
    flash[:success] = "Photo successfully created!"
    if VALID_REDIRECT_ACTIONS.include?(params[:redirect])
      redirect_to params[:redirect]
    else
      redirect_to @photo
    end
  else
    ...
  end
end
```